# Load a page from javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, wso2

I'm using jaggery for server side. I've created a login page. Once the correct user pass is entered a .jag file is set to load.

```
<%
    var user = {
        name : "Asiri Liyana Arachchi",        
    };
    session.put("admin", user);  
%>
```

I want to load the admin page from this .jag file. I've tried

```
window.location.href = "Version%204/index.html";
```

But it didn't work.How to solve this. 
Thanks

Comment: what you have done is redirect ur browser to that page.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
response.sendRedirect("/index.html");
```